# Excel 2010 vlookup #n/a error while value exists

Tags: excel

I am trying to use :

> VLOOKUP to get the value of the ID colum in the below image :

[image]

The formula returns #N/A error although the value exists!

The formula I am using is :

```
=VLOOKUP(J13,$C$2:$D$10,1,FALSE)
```

Need help resolving this please.
Thanks.

Comment: Use INDEX/MATCH. For VLOOKUP, the value must exist in the *leftmost* column of the lookup table. That is not the case here (i.e. Wael Fareed does not exist in column C).

Comment: @BigBen I am using col_index_num 1 which is the ID column for the table_array !?

Answer (score 1):

Use index() with match().
Vlookup() only works to the right of the indexing column.

So:

```
=index(C2:C10,match(J13,D2:D10,0))
```

Or you could do the lazy solution of swapping col C with Col D, but other formulae you have may then fail...

Comment: Thanks , It worked when i swapped columns :)

Comment: @wfareed you would serve yourself better by implementing index() with match() as that is **so** much more flexible.